# Error Add Foreign Key Using Install Schema Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, install-script, upgradeschema, foreign-key

```
<?php namespace Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

 public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, 
 ModuleContextInterface $context)
 {

 $newsTableName = $setup->getTable('magneto_book_free_layout');

if($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($newsTableName) != true) {

  $newsTable = $setup->getConnection()
      ->newTable($newsTableName)
      ->addColumn(
          'id',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
          null,
          ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
          'id'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'name',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          255,
          ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
            'name'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'email',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          null,
          ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
            'email'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'phoneno',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          null,
          ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true],
            'phoneno'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'heigth',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          null,
          ['nullable' => false],
            'heigth'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'width',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          null,
          ['nullable' => false],
            'width'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'image',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          null,
          ['nullable' => false],
            'image'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'entity_id',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
          null,
          ['nullable' => false],
            'entity_id'
      )
      ->addColumn(
          'status',
          \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
          null,
          ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'status'
      )
      ->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName(
                'magneto_book_free_layout',
                'entity_id',
                'catalog_product_entity',
                'entity_id'
            ),
            'entity_id',
            $installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity'), 
            'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )
      ->setComment("News Table");



  $setup->getConnection()->createTable($newsTable);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: installer in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Magneto/BookFreeLayout/Setup/InstallSchema.php on line 84

Comment: use $setup variable instead of $installer

Comment: @YashShah After Using Setup It Shows Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity_id column should look like this.

```
->addColumn(
      'entity_id',
      \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
      null,
      ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'index' => true],
      'entity_id'
)
```

Comment: I Want To Give foreign key to that column if i write primary then it will become primary key

Comment: Primary and Identity are 2 different concept. Identity is auto increament while primary is not. And the reference table has assigned it as primary so if you want to have foreign key with that table, you must define it as primary as per database concepts or else it wont allow you to do that.

Comment: Thank Buddy For You Valuable Time  It Will Helped Me Alot